# draw square and rotate it?

Tags: html, canvas, rotation

how come this doesn't work? does rotate only work with images?

```
            context.moveTo(60,60);
            context.lineTo(200,60);
            context.lineTo(200,200);
            context.lineTo(60,200);
            context.lineTo(60,60);


            context.stroke();
            context.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
            context.restore();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are rotating the whole canvas when you use `context.rotate`, and since the pivot point is defaulted at the coordinates (0, 0), your square sometimes will be drawn out of bounds.

By moving the pivot point to the middle of the square, you can then rotate it successfully.

**Note**: Make sure you rotate the canvas before you draw the square.

```
// pivot point coordinates = the center of the square
var cx = 130; // (60+200)/2
var cy = 130; // (60+200)/2

// Note that the x and y values of the square 
// are relative to the pivot point.
var x = -70; // cx + x = 130 - 70 = 60
var y = -70; // cy + y = 130 - 70 = 60
var w = 140; // (cx + x) + w = 60 + w = 200
var h = 140; // (cy + y) + h = 60 + h = 200
var deg = 45;

context.save();

context.translate(cx, cy);
context.rotate(deg * Math.PI/180);

context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

context.restore();
```

Explanation:

- `context.save();` saves the current state of the coordinate system.
- `context.translate(cx, cy);` moves the pivot point.
- `context.rotate(deg * Math.PI/180);` rotates the square to `deg` degrees (Note that the parameter is in radians, not degrees)
- `context.fillRect( x, y, w, h );` draws the square
- `context.restore();` restores the last state of the coordinate system.

Here is a [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrHV2/).

Here is another [JS Fiddle example that features a HTML5 slider](http://jsfiddle.net/HYuaf/).

Comment: is there a way to make this rotate without a slider, rather by touching the object itself?